# data-mage-init not loading js component

Tags: magento-2.1

In a ko template (abc.html) I have the following

```
<div data-mage-init='{"a_script":{} }'></div>.
```

I made sure that requirejs-config.js loaded the correct config

```
'a_script' : 'namespace/js/a_script'
```

and that "a_script.js" file exists. At runtime, abc.html gets loaded but the data-mage-init is not initialized or run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to accomplish this with M2's [mageInit](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html#mageinit) databind

```
<div data-bind='mageInit: {"a_script":{}}'></div>
```

Comment: Glad that it helped.